# How to name a function like a relation (dependence atom)

Tags: relation-symbols

I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

how do i do this for an arbitrary relation symbol?
Latex is putting a whitespace after it.

Comment: You may try one or some negative space(s) (`\!`) after the symbol to remove the whitespace folowing... or even some `\hspace{-0.5em}` or `\kern-0.5em` etc.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Perhaps try with `\mathord{<relation>}` or `{<relation>}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is necessarily a good idea, but you can just define a new operator:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator\eq{=}

\begin{document}

\[
  \eq(t_1, \dots, t_n)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: with the equal sign this is common practice in dependence logic.